# java generics Bound mismatch: The type is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

Tags: java, generics

```
    public class XYZ {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

        C<A> c = new D<A>();
```

I get an error::: Bound mismatch: The type A is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends B<T>> of the type C<T> . What am I doing wrong?
          }

```
    }

    class D<T extends B<T>> implements C<T>{
      @Override
      public void ok(T b) {
        System.out.println(b.getId());   
      }  
    }

    interface C<T extends B<T>>{
      void ok(T b);
    }

    class A extends B<String>{
    }

    class B<T>{
      private T id;

      public T getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a wildcard `B<?>`. The problem is `C<T extends B<T>>`. You give C and B the type `T`. But you declare `C<A>`. So in your case `B` gets also the type `A`, but your code says `class A extends B<String>`, where `B` has to be a `String`. The same problem in `D`. Hopefully my answer is clear.

The following code should work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    C<A> t = new D<A>();
}

static class D<T extends B<?>> implements C<T> {
    @Override
    public void ok(T b) {
        System.out.println(b.getId());
    }
}

interface C<T extends B<?>> {
    void ok(T b);
}

static class A extends B<String> {
}

static class B<T> {
    private T id;

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```